# Layout da página controlada por javascript utilizando REST para o conteúdo dinâmico

Tags: php, javascript, rest, gui

Estava pensando em um padrão diferente para desenvolver minha aplicação via browser. Como se trata de um ERP, preciso de uma interface rápida que não precise fazer download do HTML do servidor a todo momento para imprimir na tela do usuário o layout. A solução seria fazer toda a interface em javascript, puxando o conteúdo dinâmico via PHP REST com JSON. O servidor só seria responsável em imprimir um JSON para retornar apenas variáveis primitivas, como textos, inteiros, boolean e arrays.

**Dúvidas:**

**1.** Isso é um *design pattern* aceitável e profissional ou é gambiarra?

**2.** Existe algum framework javascript que me poupe trabalho na parte do cliente(javascript) para essa finalidade?

**3.** Quais pros e contras de utilizar esse *design pattern*?

Comment: Sim, é aceitável e está em alta. Se chama SinglePage Application ou SPA.  

Existem diversos frameworks como KnockOutJs, EmberJs, AngularJs, BackboneJs que fazer o controle do DOM e a manutenção de regras MVW (Model View Whatever)

Comment: Não entendo qual tipo de melhoria poderia ser aproveitada, criando todo o layout em javascript, acho que para conteúdo estático, usar apenas html, garante muito mais a exibição da página, pois se o usuário estiver com javascript desabilitado, todo seu site, não será nem visualizado.

Comment: Sim, conteudo estatico seria em HTML. O Javascript só seria responsavel por fazer as requisições no servidor para pegar as informações em JSON e fazer o controle do DOM como disseste. Ficou mais fácil pesquisar agora sabendo que isso se chama SPA e com suas sugestões de frameworks.

Quanto ao javascript desabilitado, é um mal que vou ter que combater, forçar os usuários a habilitar. Na verdade, nem me preocupo com isso, já que será uma aplicação comercial/empresarial com usuários específicos e todos seriam treinados para utilizar e obviamente não iriam desabilitar o javascript.

Comment: Neste caso sim, é vantagem, como é um ERP, não há a necessidade de se preocupar com SEO, que é um problema quando se fala de requisições Ajax, o que também existe técnicas para contornar...

Comment: @GustavoPiucco não sei se já começou a fazer mas recomendo uma olhada no nodejs para fazer o backend. Tem uma performance e escalabilidade ótima, e a curva de aprendizado não é tão grande para quem já conhece de JavaScript

Comment: Ainda não comecei. Estou ciente do NodeJS, só que como estou pensando a longo prazo, como o NodeJS aparentemente saiu do forno agora, não sei qual será o futuro do desenvolvimento do mesmo, me sinto mais seguro desenvolvendo em PHP, talvez eu esteja errado.

Comment: É, para um ERP fica bom. MAS... tem que haver um compromisso muito sério com o padrão adotado. No momento em que se começar a entregar HTML dentro de um JSON abandone o barco :D

Comment: @GustavoPiucco para nós brasileiros tem pouco tempo, mas o node já tem mais de 2 anos e está sendo abraçado por inúmeras empresas de grande porte. Como você mesmo disse, como é a longo prazo, uma tecnologia que já está despontando hoje pode ser uma boa escolha.

Comment: Ou angularJs, daquela pequena empresa...

Comment: @GustavoPiucco Faltou esclarecer algo na minha resposta? Pode adicionar um comentário que eu tentarei complementar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## MVC ou MVP ou MVVM

*(Model-View-Controller / Model-View-Presenter / Model-View-ViewModel)*
*(A escolha depende do que se adequa melhor a você e ao que quer fazer)*

Desta forma você divide as regras da aplicação em camadas.
No **Model**, você pode criar todas as entidades e regras de negócio principais em um **WebService** em qualquer linguagem ou plataforma e, a partir dele, disponibilizar o dados e interagir com sua página Web, sem existir um vínculo real entre ambos. Apenas um **contrato** da interface pública do Model para o FronEnd.

## Vantagens da divisão em camadas

Dividir sua aplicação separando a `View` do código você tem diversas vantagens:

- Redução do tráfego de rede
- Redução da carga do servidor de aplicação
- Navegação mais dinâmica e fluída
- Independência entre as equipes de Front-End e Back-End que só precisam estabelecer as funções e assinaturas dos métodos que serão expostos

## Frameworks

Dentre estes frameworks posso citar:

### [KnockOutJs](http://www.knockoutjs.com)

---

É um framework Model View ViewModel que fornece `Two-Way binding` entre o DOM e o ViewModel em javascript

Faz com que o DOM se atualize quando houver atualização na ViewModel e atualiza a ViewModel automaticamente quando ocorrer alteração no DOM

*Tenho algumas coisas atrasadas aqui, assim que terminar complemento mais a resposta com os outros frameworks e exemplos*

### [EmberJS](http://www.emberjs.com)

---

Ember.js é um framework Javascript para desenvolvimento client-side de páginas web baseado na arquitetura MVC. Permite aos criar SPA (Single Page Aplications) de forma scalável, incorporando diversos recursos além de templates auto-atualizáveis baseada no Handlebars.js

### [AngularJs](http://angularjs.org)

O AngularJs é um framework MVW (Model View Whatever) que permite que você utilize **(to be continued...)**

---

### [BackBoneJs](http://backbonejs.com)

---